# How to query multiple databases using Sequel

Tags: ruby

I have a project which contains multiple databases in a directory structure like this:

```
folder1
|_ sub1
  |_ db1
  |_ db2
|_ sub2
  |_ db1
  |_ d2
```

I would like to run one query against all the databases.

Is there a way to do this using Sequel, or would I need to traverse the directory and create a new database connection for each database, then run the query?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple ways but I'd do it like this untested code:

```
%w[
  sqlite://folder1/sub1/db1.db
  sqlite://folder1/sub1/db2.db
  sqlite://folder1/sub2/db1.db
  sqlite://folder1/sub2/db2.db
].map{ |dsn|
  DB = Sequel.connect(dsn)
  DB[:some_table].where('some' => 'value').all
}
```

This iterates over the DSNs for each database, opens a connection and returns the result as an array of results.

What those are is undefined since we have no idea what your table schemas are.